# regex how to detect special characters that are not encoded

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, encoding, frontend

If I have a string like `"this%25is a%string %"` how can I come up with a regex expression that can detect and replace the "%" signs that arent followed by a "25"? So I would wanna leave the %25 alone since its already encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead

```
/%(?!(25))/
```

This would match any `%` not followed by `25`

[more on this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)